# Можно ли заменить поле формы модели в Django?

Tags: python, django, form

есть форма, поле 'sizes' присутствует в модели в виде ManyToManyField

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, initial=1)

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = (
        'sizes',
        'quantity',

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        product_id = kwargs.pop('product_id', None)
        super(AddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        self.fields['sizes'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=product.sizes.all())
```

как можно скрыть поле sizes при рендере страницы и установить для него определённое значение,
делал так:

```
        self.fields['sizes'] = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

но в таком случае появляется скрытый инпут, где value="<'QuerySet []>", т.е. пустой запрос, хотя я же указываю, что initial=False
нужно это для того чтобы не показывать поле "размер" для товаров, где он не нужен.

Comment: В чем проблема вообще его не отображать, и заполнять при сохранении формы?

Comment: да, спасибо, я так уже и поступил :)